# Nginx with multiple locations serving some php files as download

Tags: php, nginx

I have two directories, /home/php/www/public/ and /home/php/www/private/ and I would like to serve which one depending on the first part of the uri.

I would like /foo/ to act 'normally' in that it should serve which ever file is in the location, for example mysite.com/about would serve /public/about.php. However /private/ would always serve a single file no matter the request, for example mysite.com/private/foo, mysite.com/private/bar and mysite.com/private/foo/test would all serve /private/app.php.

I am probably in the 100s of different variations from what I have seen here and in other googles but being very new to all of this can't seem to piece together exactly what I need. After a few days of trial and error I am close to what I am after, mysite.com/about serves /public/about.php correctly and mysite.com/private/whatever gets /private/app.php but it doesn't execute it, it serves it as a download instead.

Here is what I have so far:

```
server {                                                                                 

        listen 80;                                                                       
        listen [::]:80;                                                                  

        root /home/php/www/public;                                                       

        index index.php;                                                                 

        server_name mysite.com;                                        

        location /private/ {                                                                
                alias /home/php/www/private;                                                 
                try_files /app.php =404;                                              

                location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {                                              
#               location ~ \.php$ {                                                      
#                       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;                        
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;                               
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;                      

#                       fastcgi_index app.php;                                        
#                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#                       include fastcgi_params;                                          

#                       return 302 https://google.com;                                   
                }                                                                        
        }                                                                                

        location / {                                                                     
                try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;                       
        }                                                                                

        location ~ \.php$ {                                                              
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;                                       
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location @extensionless-php {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

If I replace everything inside the `location /private/` block with just `return 302 https://google.com` it redirects successfully to google.com, so I know this location block is being returned but putting the same thing inside the `location ~ \.php$` inside `location /private/` nothing happens so to me it looks like it is not hitting this block, what am I missing? There aren't any errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log relating to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
location /private/ {                                                                
    root /home/php/www/private;
    try_files /app.php =404;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

Use `root` rather than `alias` as you are not trying to alias the original request. The file was downloaded because of the unnecessary nested `location` block.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond Richard. I have tried your suggestion, changing it to root hasn't changed anything but I assume is the correct way of doing it so thank you. I have had to remove the 2 lines for php from this location block as I get `nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5` I guess because there is already a block just for this further down, but why is it not getting matched? I need that block there to deal with the other pages so can't remove it, can I?

Comment: If you don't want to unpick `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`, you could change the first `try_files` statement to `rewrite ^ /app.php break;` and see if that works.

Comment: Ok it wasn't because of the block below it, removing `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` cleared the nginx error but it still isn't working.

Comment: Sorry hadn't refreshed the page before commenting. I have tried that, it still isn't picking up the PHP and is getting served as a download.